# check while loop out put any data from query

Tags: php

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT *...
while($data=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){...}
```

I have a query use while loop print out the data.

How can I check if while loop didn't fetch out any data(0 row from db), so I can print "0 result" on screen.

I don't want to make extra query for COUNT(*), is any way do check from while loop?

Comment: `if (!$data)` may do the trick

Comment: Between `prepare()` and `fetch()`, you have to call `execute()`... just sayin' ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a flag inside the loop to ensure you entered at least once.

Something like:

```
$flag = false;
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT *...");
while($data=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $flag = true;
}
if ($flag) {} //entered
```

Added semicolon, thanks [@Fred -ii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii)

Comment: Missing ending semi-colon for `$flag = false`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$sth = $query->execute()` (and `$sth->fetch()` instead of $query->fetch() )  first, then `$sth->rowCount` will give you the number of results.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to count the amount of results you get. In that case, you can just count a var up inside the loop:

```
while($data=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $i++;
    //your code here
}
```

If you want to check if you got no data, you can check `$data`:

```
while($data=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($data === false) {
       echo "0 result";
    }
}
```